# Blade @inject creates new Singleton instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have BreadcrumbService, which is registered as Singleton in AppServiceProvider

```
public $singletons = [
    BreadcrumbService::class => BreadcrumbService::class,
];
```

When I inject it into my Controller via `__construct` method, everything works great. I fill breadcrumbs in controller action and return view. But in view if I use `@inject` directive, it creates new instance event it is registered as singleton.

```
@inject('breadcrumbs', '\SunApp\Services\BreadcrumbService')
@php
    var_dump(resolve(\SunApp\Services\BreadcrumbService::class)->isActive());
    var_dump($breadcrumbs->isActive());
@endphp
```

First `var_dump` prints out `true`, second `false`. Is this a bug or I missed something in behaviour of `@inject`

Comment: is this something like View Composer ?

Comment: @kenken9999 I don't understand. `@inject` is default Laravel directive https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#service-injection I do not use View composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the starting slash from that class name.

`'\Something\Else' != 'Something\Else'`

Without the slash its finding the binding. With the slash it isn't, as the name doesn't match, so it just ends up `new`ing up a new instance. PHP requires you to use the fully qualified name for the class if you want to call `new` with a string when the class is in a namespace anyway.

Conclusion: There is not a problem with `@inject` as it is only calling `app($service)`. This is just how the Application container looks up bindings. These bindings are strings, that just happen to sometimes be FQCNs, they could just be any random strings.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I thought service container works different. But about your first line: "It would be better to use the class constant most likely there.". If I put this `@inject('breadcrumbService', SunApp\Services\BreadcrumbService::class)` it doesn't work. Blade will quote second parametr, this is from compiled template: `<?php $breadcrumbService = app('SunApp\Services\BreadcrumbService::class'); ?>`